PHP SimpleXML does not parse array of nodes correctly
I have an XML with an list of nodes of the same name:
<object>
    <attributes>
        <attribute id="1" name="first">First Value</attribute>
        <attribute id="2" name="second">Second Value</attribute>
        <attribute id="3" name="third">Third Value</attribute>
    </attributes>
</object>

When i try to convert this using SimpleXML:
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<object>
    <attributes>
        <attribute id="1" name="first">First Value</attribute>
        <attribute id="2" name="second">Second Value</attribute>
        <attribute id="3" name="third">Third Value</attribute>
    </attributes>
</object>
XML;
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($obj);

i do not get the attribute nodes attributes (id, name):
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [attributes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [attribute] => Array
                (
                    [0] => First Value
                    [1] => Second Value
                    [2] => Third Value
                )

        )

)


You mean you don't see them with print_r(). Try: print_r($obj->attributes->attribute);. This just means that print_r() isn't the best way to view the content of a SimpleXMLElement object, nothing more. Use the methods of the SimpleXMLElement object instead.

Thank you, but i also tried it the "tradtional way" making the object to an JSON an back to an array
$json = json_encode($obj);
$meta = json_decode($json,TRUE);
print_r($meta);```
That does not show it either, so i assume it is not present in the XML object at all. Maybe the parser is not able to handle this kind of nesting?

How about reading the duplicate question? The answer is there.
